# Will the improper use of tables ever go away in HTML?

Tags: html, html-table, w3c

It seems that the use of tables is now primarily based on the wild west of web development where the W3C spec is not respected and where developers go to torture themselves... I'm speaking of email clients.

Obviously some email clients using alternate parsers (such as Outlook using MS Word's renderer) require the use of tables. However, as web based clients become more popular and with OS based clients [usage stats on the decline](http://emailclientmarketshare.com/), the majority user base is fast becoming email clients in which should (some do) support CSS.

Also side from the use of displaying form data, standard HTML layout would probably never use tables, correct? Aside from form data could it be safe to say that **tables in modern HTML layout** is now becoming depreciated?

Comment: What about for displaying *actual* table data?

Comment: I mentioned that above :)

Comment: Hmm, not really.  If you need to display a table of, say, numbers, then a `<table>` is the obvious (and correct) choice.  I'm not sure what this has to do with email.

Comment: Other than forms data, as mentioned, email templating is the only other place I can think of using tables.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data. No, they will never go away.

Comment: You mean apart from things that are semantically tabular?  e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence.

Comment: That's a great example of displaying form data right Oliver?

Comment: Use of tables in HTML will be always there. But , it depends on the requirement . Basically with rapidly growing technologies which boon us several browser.

Comment: But it's not a form...

Comment: @Oliver Oh I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: @sevenseacat tables where originally for layout. And they are still being used for such in email clients.

Comment: You understand what a form is, right?

Comment: Tables were never 'originally' for layout. They got abused that way sure, but they were never intended for layout purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, tables will not (and should not) go away.

They are the correct way to control the format and presentation of tabular data.

*"Obviously some email clients using alternate parsers (such as Outlook using MS Word's renderer) require the use of tables"*  Well they might use them, especially for the 'many rows with many columns' part of the interface, but they may well use them for layout too, depending on the approach.

*"Aside from form data "*  This is a good example. They are frequently used for forms but css can and increasingly should be used instead.

Comment: What about in regards to standard layout?

Comment: Please define that term.  I googled and didn't see an immediate answer.

Comment: Semantic layout within HTML5 markup for web pages and their content. Also thank you for putting effort into this answer.

Comment: Please be more specific I don't get what part of Semantic Layout you mean, sorry.

Comment: Sure, We use HTML tags such as article, heading, footer etc because of the spec and their semantic reasons for existing. Today, we would not build any web page without these new additions of HTML, and to my point, we would never replace them with tables, rows and cells. Correct?

Comment: @BenRacicot: Yes, in general, you shouldn't use `<table>` for something that isn't semantically a table.  No-one is disputing that.

Comment: Then as far as tables go, they should NEVER be used in standard web page layout, only tabular data forms.

Comment: @BenRacicot: I really don't understand what distinction you're trying to make. Firstly, tables and forms are not the same thing.  Secondly, in cases where the content is *semantically a table*, then a `<table>` is always the correct thing to use (I'm not sure what "standard web page layout" is).

Comment: @Oliver it seems like you're not trying to understand what I'm saying and you're trying to discredit the question.

Comment: @BenRacicot: Yes, I definitely don't understand what you're saying.  "Standard web layout" is not a conventional phrase, and tables are not forms, nor vice versa.  Until you explain what you mean more clearly, this conversation is destined to go round in circles (with the invariant that tables *are* still appropriate for tables).

Comment: Tables rows and cells are used to create online forms correct? Its very common? Perhaps the most common way to display data, much like your example?

Comment: @BenRacicot: But my example was *not* a form.  Perhaps the issue here is that you misunderstand the term "form".

Comment: I understand what you're saying.. My b. the term form is misleading . A form is a form, a table of data is a table. Guess there's no other way to say it...

Comment: Tables should not be used for forms. Forms are not tabular data. Tables are for tabular data, with rows and columns of related data, with captions, column headings, footers, etc.